Backspace does not work on vim mode in Mac OS terminal
I am using ZSH on Mac terminal and I enable vi mode in the terminal by adding set -o vi  to my ~/.zshrc. When I am in the prompt line, and I type Hello, then I hit Esc to enter the non-insert mode, move my cursor to e and hit i to enter insert mode, I can not erase the H by hitting the backspace key.
Note that backspace key works on this same scenario when I open up a new file using vim test.txt and writing Hello and following the steps above, so I don't think this is a vim settings issue.
Also, I ran vi --version in my ~/.zshrc right before set -o vi  and this is part of the output I got: VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0 (2022 Jun 28, compiled Feb 10 2024 02:02:30)
Please help me!

vi-mode in zsh in neither vi nor vim, it's vi emulation in zsh. It's meaningless to look at vi --version or ~/.vimrc — they have nothing with vi-mode in zsh.

Thanks! Any idea how I can achieve my goal?

Nope, sorry. I use bash and default mode.

What happens if you press the apple-key together with backspace key, i.e. command backspace? BTW, this question is better asked at [apple.se]. If you ask there, don't forget to also specify, what hardware you are using, which terminal application, and which OS version.

command backspace also does not work :( I will ask it there- thanks

Just because someone is using a Mac doesn’t mean it automatically belongs on Ask Different.  This really is a zsh question; they’d have the same problem no matter what system they were using.

Try bindkey -M viins "^?" backward-delete-char.
Backspace is normally bound to vi-backward-delete-char, which is specifically documented to not do what you’re asking:

vi-backward-delete-char (unbound) (X) (^H)
Delete the character behind the cursor, without changing lines.  If in insert mode, this won't delete past the point where insert mode was last entered.

backward-delete-char doesn’t have that restriction.

Can you please share how you got the description for vi-backward-delete-char (unbound) (X) (^H)

It’s in the man page, zshzle(1), under Standard Widgets > Modifying Text.
